# Should Java variables be initialised on declaration?

Tags: java

Simple question, but interested to know if it is good practice to initialize Java variables on declaration?  I am not really consistent; I tend to initialize Booleans but nothing else.  For example:

```
private Boolean test = false;
private Integer count;
```

I am sure this is a really basic question, but I am interested to know the why and when?

Comment: Better if you do so when it comes to code management. If you do not initialize them, they will contain a garbage value  which JVM has given to them.

Comment: @JudeNiroshan Not in Java. Object(s) will be `null`. Primitive(s) will have their corresponding default values. Still this question is asking for opinion.

Comment: For code clarity reason.... i would also initialize the `count` to null. Even though I know that object by default it will be null if its not initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Java Practices](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=14), the JVM will implicitly set the following default values:

- numbers: 0 or 0.0
- booleans: false
- object references: null

In fact, if you explicitly set these values, you risk causing operations to be performed *twice*. Take a look at the following example class and its bytecode compiled using Oracle's `javac`:

```
public final class Quark {

  public Quark(String aName, double aMass){
    fName = aName;
    fMass = aMass;
  }

  //PRIVATE

  //WITHOUT redundant initialization to default values
  //private String fName;
  //private double fMass;

  //WITH redundant initialization to default values
  private String fName = null;
  private double fMass = 0.0d;
}
```

Without redundancy

```
>javap -c -classpath . Quark 
Compiled from Quark.java 
public final class Quark extends java.lang.Object { 
    public Quark(java.lang.String,double); 
}
Method Quark(java.lang.String,double) 
   0 aload_0 
   1 invokespecial #1 <Method java.lang.Object()> 
   4 aload_0 
   5 aload_1 
   6 putfield #2 <Field java.lang.String fName> 
   9 aload_0 
  10 dload_2 
  11 putfield #3 <Field double fMass> 
  14 return
```

And with redundancy:

```
>javap -c -classpath . Quark 
Compiled from Quark.java 
public final class Quark extends java.lang.Object { 
    public Quark(java.lang.String,double); 
}
Method Quark(java.lang.String,double) 
   0 aload_0 
   1 invokespecial #1 <Method java.lang.Object()> 
   4 aload_0 
   5 aconst_null 
   6 putfield #2 <Field java.lang.String fName> 
   9 aload_0 
  10 dconst_0 
  11 putfield #3 <Field double fMass> 
  14 aload_0 
  15 aload_1 
  16 putfield #2 <Field java.lang.String fName> 
  19 aload_0 
  20 dload_2 
  21 putfield #3 <Field double fMass> 
  24 return
```

Comment: This is really helpful - and I thought it was a benign question!  So you are saying that it is better to let the JVM do its work?

Comment: With the above consideration, there is some personal preference in the decision. If they are _not_ initialized, someone could make the assumption that it was in error and that another default value should have been set. If you don't believe that additional clarity is necessary, then do like you said: let the JVM do its thing.

Answer (score 1):

This might even be an opinion based solution, but I would usually **avoid** initializing it on declaration(with some exceptions as below). As primitive data types have default values and objects have null references, there are occurrences where I initialize as well.

However, I have initialized in this case:

```
public class Initializer{
   private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

//Getters and //Setters

}
```

This is opinion based ofcourse. I initialize `Array` and other `Collection`s alone as sometimes they cause `NullPointerException` on my Service layer. Yes people would recommend to modify Getters instead. But I prefer to Initialize only on certain occurrences and not every time.

Answer (score 0):

**Opinion:** *Fields* have well-defined default values (null, 0, false), and you shouldn't initialize them unless they need to be initialized to a non-default value.

However your question title was about *variables*, and my opinion is that you also shouldn't initialize variables, *unless needed*. The "need" is about variables being `undefined` (not garbage) until initialized. You simply cannot retrieve a value from a variable unless that variable is [*definitely assigned*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html).

I sometimes see the following:

```
int a = 0;
if (/*insert expression here*/)
    a = 10;
else
    a = 20;
```

The initializer is extraneous, useless, and misleading. *(My true opinion uses stronger words)*

Answer (score 0):

I say primitives, no. Objects, yes. If for no other reason than to make it explicitly clear when you want something initialized to null. This also helps illuminate some of your null values when debugging.